# Even elements in a cyclic group

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $n$ is an even positive integer and $H$ is a subgroup of $Z_n$. Prove that either every member of $H$ is even or exactly half the members of $H$ are even.

Let $n=2m$. I think every subgroup of $Z_{2m}$ will be the set of non-negative multiples of $k  $ less than $2m$ for all $k$ which are divisors of $2m$. Is this conjecture true? If yes, how to prove it? Proving this solves the above problem.

Comment: What have you done so far? If you provide your work it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your idea, you can prove it by picking some number $a\leq n$ and note that there exists $p, q\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $pa+qn=\gcd(a, n)$. Then $k:=\gcd(a, n)$ is the number you are after. (Note that you will still need to prove that $\langle a\rangle=\langle k\rangle$. This is not hard, but it does need done.)

A perhaps slightly slicker way to prove the result is to consider the image of $H$ under the canonical map $\mathbb{Z}_{2m}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_2$. The result follows immediately.

As an aside, consider the following question: what do you mean by an "even" element if $H$? Is this well-defined? What about if $n$ were odd, would it still be well-defined?